# Django DB Constraint with grandfathered data / Ignore UniqueConstraint for a test?

Tags: python, django, database, unit-testing, constraints

Recently added a `UniqueConstraint` to a model (`Project`) to enforce uniqueness with no problems.

```py
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_unique_name_in_organization",
                fields=['organization', 'name']
            )
        ]
```

As I understand database constraints, they do not work retroactively. This creates a blindspot as I am uncertain how the grandfathered entities will behave on future database interactions (e.g. will an `IntegrityError` be raised when saving even if the only change is for an unrelated field?). To remedy this, I've tried creating a test that populates the test database with a few entities that have the known conflict (e.g. a shared `name` and `organization`), but as expected Django raises `IntegrityError`.

**How can I circumvent this and create purposely bad data that conflicts with my database constraint?**

I've tried:

```py
with connection.constraint_checks_disabled()
    Project.objects.create(
        ...
```

```py
with mock.patch.object(Project._meta, 'constraints', return_value=[]):
    Project.objects.create(
        ...
```

```py
with mock.patch.object(Project._meta, 'constraints', new_callable=mock.PropertyMock) as cmock:
    cmock.return_value = []
    Project.objects.create(
        ...
```

However, an `IntegrityError` is still raised for each attempt.

I've tried deleting the constraint with some `sql`, but that raises `django.db.utils.OperationalError: cannot ALTER TABLE "app_project" because it has pending trigger events`

```py
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            table = Project._meta.db_table
            sql_ = sql.SQL("ALTER TABLE {table} DISABLE TRIGGER ALL").format(table=sql.Identifier(table))
            cursor.execute(sql_)
            cursor.commit()
            sql_ = sql.SQL(
                "ALTER TABLE {table} DROP CONSTRAINT {constraint}")\
                .format(table=sql.Identifier(Project._meta.db_table),
                        constraint=sql.Identifier(
                            Project._meta.constraints[0].name))
            cursor.execute(sql_)
            cursor.commit()
```